# Why does my rspec-rails generated spec fail due to a routing exception?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I generated a scaffold with Rails (4.1.16) and Rspec (3.5.1).

It generated this test:

```
describe "GET #show" do
  it "assigns the requested team as @team" do
    team = Team.create! valid_attributes
    get :show, params: {id: team.to_param}, session: valid_session
    expect(assigns(:team)).to eq(team)
  end
end
```

Which outputs this error:

```
TeamsController GET #show assigns the requested team as @team
 Failure/Error: get :show, params: {id: team.to_param}, session: valid_session

 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"teams", :params=>{:id=>"82"}, :session=>{}}
```

If I remove the keys to the parameters to `get`, i.e.:

```
get :show, {id: team.to_param}, valid_session
```

The test passes fine.

Not sure what gem defines the generator template (rspec-rails?) and why I get this error. Help would be appreciated understanding this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generator (`rspec:scaffold`, which comes with rspec-rails) is generating tests with [the syntax required by Rails 5](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/04/19/changes-to-test-controllers-in-rails-5.html) (see the last section of that blog post), which is not compatible with Rails 4. I think this is a bug in rspec-rails, since rspec-rails 3.5 is otherwise compatible with Rails 4. (I'm using those versions together myself; I just haven't used the generator.)

rspec-rails was [changed to use the Rails 5 syntax](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/pull/1603) [in rspec-rails 3.5.0.beta4](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/compare/v3.5.0.beta3...v3.5.0.beta4), so one workaround is to use rspec and rspec-rails 3.4 — not so nice since the newer versions have features and fixes which are as useful with Rails 4 as with Rails 5. Another workaround is to manually fix the output of the generator as you did.

Comment: Awesome answer. Thanks.